# Spring MVC controller mapping problems

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, deployment, web

I'm new to Spring MVC and trying to learn from some web tutorials and Spring's PetClinic.  When I was just starting I was using some tutorials from some really old releases of Spring.  I didn't know it at the time, so it has been a lot of back and an regroup attempts.  I am having trouble with the way my test site finds the Controller classes.  The site finds my index.jsp file and executes that just fine.  But when I try to click on a link that maps to one the the Controller classes I get a page not found (404) error.

Everything compiles and deployes with no errors on JBoss EAP 6.1.
  I'm attaching some of the snippets from my config files.  Can somebody look at them and see what I'm doing wrong>

Web.xml snippet:

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:resources/spring/core-config.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

the dispatcher servlet.xml snippet:

```
    <bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

<bean class="org.S2Me.MyHealth.controller.CustomMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound">notFound</prop>
            <prop key="java.lang.Exception">failure</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
>
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />
</bean>
```

the core-Servlet snippet:

```
   <import resource="view-config.xml"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="org.S2Me.MyHealth.controller" />

 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**"  location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/>

<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index" />

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
    p:basename="messages/messages" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver"
>
    <property name="defaultErrorView" value="exception" />
    <!-- results into 'WEB-INF/jsp/exception.jsp' -->
    <property name="warnLogCategory" value="warn" />
</bean>
```

the view-Servlet snippet:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver"
>
    <property name="contentNegotiationManager" ref="cnManager" />
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
            >
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            </bean>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="cnManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true"/>
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="text/html"/>

    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
            <entry key="atom" value="application/atom+xml" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The index.jsp snippet:

```
    <div class="navbar-inner">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li style="width: 100px;"><a href="<spring:url value="/" htmlEscape="true" />"><i class="icon-home"></i>
            Home</a></li>
        <li style="width: 130px;">
        <a href="<spring:url value="/login" htmlEscape="true" />"> Login</a>
        </li>
                </ul>
</div>
```

The Login Controller class:

```
package org.S2Me.MyHealth.controller;

import org.S2Me.MyHealth.server.LoginForm;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;

import java.util.Map;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController
{

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showForm(Map model)
    {

         LoginForm loginForm = new  LoginForm();
        model.put("loginForm", loginForm);
        return "loginform";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processForm(@Valid  LoginForm loginForm, BindingResult result,
            Map model)
    {

        String userName = "UserName";
        String password = "password";
        if (result.hasErrors())
        {
            return "loginform";
        }
        loginForm = ( LoginForm) model.get("loginForm");
        if (!loginForm.getUserName().equals(userName)
                || !loginForm.getPassword().equals(password))
        {
            return "loginform";
        }
        model.put("loginForm", loginForm);
        return "loginsuccess";
    }
}
```

Any syntax errors are my cutting and pasting like I said no error in compile or deployment,  just 404 errors on navigation.
Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: You aren't loading your dispatcher-servlet.xml file.

Comment: @M. Deinum could you explain what you mean by not loading the dispatcher-servlet.xml?  I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Just as I mention. You have a dispatcher-servlet.xml (according to your post), b ut that is never loaded. You let the `DispatcherServlet` servlet load the 'core-servlet.xml' instead.

Comment: OK.  Where/how do I load the dispatcher-Servlet?  I thought that the web.xml would do that when I defined the dispatcher named servlet.  I'm not questioning your answer, just a newbie trying to learn.

Comment: That is the default, but you are overriding the default by specifing an init-param with **contextConfigLocation**...

Comment: @M. Deinum if you would care to put your comments in the form of an answer, I will mark it as accepted.  Either way thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration is ignoring the **dispatcher-servlet.xml** file.

> Upon initialization of a DispatcherServlet, Spring MVC looks for a file named [servlet-name]-servlet.xml in the WEB-INF directory of your web application and creates the beans defined there, overriding the definitions of any beans defined with the same name in the global scope. Source: [Spring Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet)

One can override this by specifing an init-param with the name `contextConfigLocation`.

As you are specifing this parameter your **dispatcher-servlet.xml** is thus ignored and with that the configuration inside of it.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know how many more days it would have taken me to get even close to solving this problem.